# How to access camel context inside processor bean

Tags: apache-camel

I would like to access existing xml context inside java code for creating producer template. Is there any annotation or any other way to achieve.

@Context context

ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void method(Exchange exchange) {
 ProducerTemplate template = exchange.getContext().createProducerTemplate();
}
```

Context can be accessed from exchange.